# Why Jupyter Notebook or Spyder execute way faster my Python code than the same .py called in windows shell?

Tags: python, shell, command-line, anaconda, runtime

My code does this:

- reads an about 460 000 row × 45 column datatable from CSV file.
- according to a filter table gives labels to the rows.
- It goes through the whole table several times during running.

In Spyder or Jupiter, the runtime is 12 seconds.
But when I run it from Windows PowerShell (python "C:\folders\xy.py") it takes 14 minutes.
The running starts immediately in both ways but in the middle where a big calculation task happens the PowerShell stops for minutes. In the Spyder there is a little delay at this point, but just 10 seconds.

My goal is to call this mainly in Shell.

Do you have an idea what can cause the problem and how to solve it?

I tried to reinstall python to have the same release in the shell too, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

that because when you use shell the code must call the system first, otherwise, when you use IDE like spyder it already call when the IDE start. you can visit this link to know more [Why is my Java program running 4 times faster via Eclipse than via shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206123/why-is-my-java-program-running-4-times-faster-via-eclipse-than-via-shell). Hope that help you. sorry if my english not good

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
But the running starts immediately, just in the middle of the code, where a big calculation task happens: for the PowerShell it takes 10 minutes, while for the Spyder it takes 10 seconds.